# Clicking is not working in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I am trying to create a bot which will fill up the signup forms for a particular website.

Website Details - http://hacknyu.org/signup

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
class HackNNYU(object):
    first_name = 'input[ng-model="credentials.first_name"]'
    last_name = 'input[ng-model="credentials.last_name"]'
    email = '.col-sm-12>input[ng-model="credentials.email"]'
    password = '.col-sm-12>input[ng-model="credentials.password"]'
    agree_checkbox = '.ng-binding>input[ng-model="checkModel"]'
    sign_up_button = 'div>button[type="submit"]'
    accept_button = 'button[ng-click="positive()"]'

def fill_up_hack_nyu():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://hacknyu.org/signup')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.first_name).send_keys('Friday')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.last_name).send_keys('Night')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300);")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.email).send_keys('ade347@gmail.edu')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.password).send_keys('123456')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.agree_checkbox).click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.accept_button).click()
    # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 400);")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.sign_up_button).click()
fill_up_hack_nyu()
```

**Problem**

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector(HackNNYU.sign_up_button).click()

The main problem is in this line. Manually when you click on `signup button` it is working fine but when I run this program, I can see it is clicking on `signup button` but nothing is happening after that. Could anyone help me why this is not working? I am just trying to register for an event using a bot. I will highly appreciate any help you can provide.

**Error**

Sometimes I always receive this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (796.4000244140625, 45.399993896484375). Other element would receive the click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page has a banner at the top which makes the automatic scrolling hide the submit button. To overcome this issue, you can define the scrolling behaviour to scroll at the bottom instead. Moreover it seems that your script is no correctly clicking on the checkbox that should display the terms popup.

Here is a working script to create a new account on hacknyu:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# set the scrolling behavior to down
DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX["elementScrollBehavior"] = 1

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# load the page
driver.get("http://hacknyu.org/signup")

# get the form element
form = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name='signupForm']")

# fill the fields
form.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='firstName']").send_keys("myfirstname")
form.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='lastName']").send_keys("mylastname")
form.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='email']").send_keys("na@na.na")
form.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("mypassword")

# click and accept terms
form.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='terms']/..").click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[.='Accept']"))).click()
wait.until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".modal")))

# click on submit
form.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you tell me why your `accept_checkbox` is working fine but not mine? You are using `xpath` and I am using `css_selector`?

Comment: I don't know why, but sometimes the checkbox doesn't take the event, so I clicked on the label of the checkbox instead. And for the dot in the XPath, it means value.

Comment: Could you explain more about DesiredCapabilities? when we want to use it?

Comment: Capabilities are the settings for the driver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Comment: Wish I can give you more points for answering my questions :) thanks

Comment: How did you know that the banner is hiding the `sign up` button ? I couldn't catch it

Comment: I knew by experience when I saw the fixed banned. Check the browser just after the exception and you'll see that the button is under the banner.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably timing issue. You can use [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) to make sure the element is clickable

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, HackNNYU.sign_up_button))).click()
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the button to be clickable before clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly providing wait or sleep before click will helps you simulate click correctly. Some situations click by using Actions also helps me. In Java

```
 Actions moveAndClick=new Actions(driver);
moveAndClick.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("HackNNYU.sign_up_button"))).click().build().perform();
```

and one more way is to use javascript executor.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("HackNNYU.sign_up_button"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Thank You,
Murali